# He had a "tongue" of hair on the top of his head

Tags: meaning

In this below article what 'He had a "tongue" of hair on the top of his head' means?

Even though he was going bald, he knew that he needed to cut his hair every two weeks.

**He had a "tongue" of hair on the top of his head.** His hair was thinning at the crown

thank you

Comment: This looks like it's from this story: http://www.rong-chang.com/eslread/eslread/ss/s002.htm.

Comment: What does a tongue look like?

Comment: @Doub Glancy:Right. i am studying with that web site:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Tongue* is used in many instances to refer to something projecting, like a tongue from a mouth.  Here's a **tongue of land**:
[image]

Here's a **tongue of fire**:
[image]

Here's the **tongue of a shoe**:

[image]

And here's a **tongue of hair**:
[image]